# Explicit function template specialization picks the wrong specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have 2 functions inside a class, one is the default specilization of the operator+= which expects a function of some sort, whilst the second specilization expects an EventHandler, here is the implementation:

```
    template<typename _Func>
    timed_function<_Sig>& operator+=( _Func &&f )
    {
        // Create an unamed handler
        auto handler = new EventHandler<_Sig>( "unamed", std::forward<_Func>( f ) );

        // Push it
        _fs.push_back( handler );

        // Return a reference to the function
        return handler->get( );
    }
```

Here's the specialized version:

```
template<>
timed_function<_Sig>& operator+=<const EventHandler<_Sig>&>( const EventHandler<_Sig> &_Handler )
{
    // Copy the handler and push it
    _fs.push_back( new EventHandler<_Sig>( _Handler ) );

    // Return a reference to the function
    return _fs.back( )->get( );
}
```

Where `_fs` is just a vector of `EventHandler<_Sig>` Pointers.
And `_Sig` being the function signature (e.g `void(int)`)

When using the += operator on for example a lambda function it works just fine and the compiler picks the correct specialization:

```
window->OnKeyDown( ) += []( dx::Window *sender, dx::KeyDownArgs &args )
{
    [...]
};
```

`OnKeyDown( )` returns a reference to an instance of `Event<void(dx::Window*, dx::KeyDownArgs&)>`

However when I try and manually add an EventHandler like this it still picks the non-specialized version of the function.

```
window->OnKeyDown( ) += EventHandler<void(dx::Window*, dx::KeyDownArgs&)>( "Key Handler", 
                        []( dx::Window *sender, dx::KeyDownArgs &args ) 
                        {
                            [...]
                        } );
```

Thanks!

Comment: `dx::EventHandler` is the same as `EventHandler`?

Comment: Yes, I'll remove it for the purpose of making it easier to understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly specialize, just use

```
template<>
timed_function<_Sig>& operator+=<const EventHandler<_Sig>>...
```

That is, remove the reference from template specialization. Here is an example of how this sort of specialization should work - with cooked-up types, but should be useful:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/297df51929329484

(depending on your compiler, you might have to put a space between '>>' in specialization).

Comment: Weirdly this causes the same exact error to be triggered around 140 times on the same line. Removing the reference from the specialization causes the compiler so say the specialization is of ill form. @SergeyA

Comment: @PsychoBitch, please provide the full code of the specialization. You definitely have an issue there.

Comment: @PsychoBitch, remove `const` and try putting a space between '>', like `<EventHandler<_Sig> >` Here is an example (with cooked-up types, just for show): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/297df51929329484

Comment: that does not fix it, I'm just gonna do something stupid instead and add a constructor to EventHandler so that the second argument can take EventHandler<_Sig> or directly a function, that way I dont need specialization.

Comment: @PsychoBitch, suit yourself, but this specialization should work. Check the example I provided.

Comment: edit that in to your post and I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: yes, just needed to change the Non-specialized version to also take a const T&, I guess universal references was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

You provide `EventHandler<_Sig>&&` not a `const EventHandler<_Sig>&`, so the non specialized version is chosen.

Comment: I figured that might be the cause, the question is how would one solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @PsychoBitch, see my answer.

Comment: @PsychoBitch: turning your template to `template<typename F> timed_function<Sig>& operator+=(const F& f)` might be a solution. SFINAE and overload an other, or partial spetialisation of (helper) struct. Or be explicit in the call as SergeyA suggests.